# Trustee vs trustor in allow trust operation

Tags: operations, trustline

When it comes to trust lines, I had assumed the trustor is the account trusting the asset and trustee is the issuing account. This supposition is backed up by the [horizon API responses](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#example-8).

In the [XDR definition for allow_trust_operation](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x#L173-L190) it defines a field only for the `trustor`, which would be the same as the source account. It has no field for the trustee. Is this field named incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which SDK you are using but the trustor should be the account setting the trust line and in the python SDK the trustee is specified in the asset definition which is Asset(symbol, issuer_public_key) so it does not need to be specified separately.

Because the allow trust operation is created by the asset issuer, the trustee is implied, but the trustor needs to be specified.

Comment: I’m writing the Scala SDK and I’m trying to unify the types for both XDR and Horizon API responses. XDR defines the allow trust operation with a `trustor`, but I suspect it should be named `trustee`, thereby defining an asset completely.